# Solve for $x$ : $x^4 = 5(x-1)(x^2 - x +1)$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Solve for $x$ : $x^4 = 5(x-1)(x^2 - x +1)$

I am having difficulty factoring the whole equation so that I can equate each factor to $0$ one by one and get the roots accordingly.

Comment: The solutions are $\left\{x = \frac{1}{4} \left(5+\sqrt{5}-i \sqrt{2
   \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right\},\left\{x =  \frac{1}{4} \left(5+\sqrt{5}+i
   \sqrt{2 \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right\},\left\{x = \frac{1}{4}
   \left(5-\sqrt{5}-i \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right\},\left\{x =
   \frac{1}{4} \left(5-\sqrt{5}+i \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right\}$

Comment: There is definitely no nice way to find them.

Comment: I used complex root finding and then radicalized and rationalized the answer.

Comment: I am just wondering when I read posts like these: Is this a text book exercise?

Comment: It is my text book question

Comment: @VishweshwarTyagi you put the `trigonometry` tag for your question. Could you provide some context why you did so?

Comment: Removed. Actually I was going through similar questions that required conversion into polar form.

Comment: @EliSadoff from the look of the roots, double completing the square should work.

Comment: divide both side by $\frac{1}{x^4}$ and change variable to $y = \frac{x-1}{x^2}$. you get a quadratic equation in $y$.

Comment: For a *nice way* to factor the whole polynomial and to deduce its roots, one can solve the identity $$x^4-5(x-1)(x^2-x+1)=(x^2-ax+a)(x^2-bx+b)$$ which happens to be equivalent to $$a+b=ab=5$$ which is solved by $$a,b=\frac{5\pm\sqrt5}2$$ and the rest is routine.

Comment: Are you looking for real of complex roots ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is your point? There are four complex roots and zero real root.

Comment: @did If the goal is to find the real roots, ad-hoc techniques can be used to show that there are none.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: let $x=y+1$, expand, regroup and collect, then the equation becomes:

$$y^4-y^3+y^2-y+1=0$$

Multiplying by $y+1 \ne 0$ gives $y^5 + 1 = 0$ having as solutions the $5^{th}$ roots of $-1$.

Comment: +1 nice observation. no wonder I find the root looks familiar.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you, mostly luck. Was actually looking for a linear substitution to "niceify" the coefficients, then all of a sudden this turned up.

Answer (score 3):

Divide both sides by $x^4$ and change variable to $y = \frac{x-1}{x^2}$, we have

$$\begin{align}1 = 5y(1-y)
\iff & 4y(y-1) = -\frac45 \iff 
(2y-1)^2 = \frac15\\
\implies & y = \frac12\left(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{5}\pm 1}{2\sqrt{5}} = \frac{2}{5 \mp \sqrt{5}}
\end{align}
$$
Substitute $y$ back by $\frac{x-1}{x^2}$, we get

$$
 x^2 - \frac{5\mp\sqrt{5}}{2} (x - 1) = 0
\iff \left(x - \frac{5\mp\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{5\mp\sqrt{5}}{2} - 
\left(\frac{5\mp\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2
= -\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{5}}{8}
$$
This leads to
$\displaystyle\;x = \frac{5 - \epsilon \sqrt{5} \pm i \sqrt{2(5 + \epsilon \sqrt{5})}}{4}$ where $\epsilon = \pm 1$.

If one insists on factoring the equation first, one can treat $x^2$ and $(x-1)$ as two seperate units and rearrange them:

$$\begin{align}
 & x^4 = 5(x-1)(x^2 - x + 1)\\
\iff & x^4 - 5x^2(x-1) + 5(x-1)^2 = 0\\
\iff & \left(x^2 - \frac52(x-1)\right)^2 = \left(\frac{25}{4} - 5\right)(x-1)^2 = \frac{5}{4}(x-1)^2\\
\iff & \left(x^2 - \frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}(x-1)\right)\left(x^2 - \frac{5 - \sqrt{5}}{2}(x-1)\right) = 0
\end{align}
$$